# Map specific columns to different pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, aggregate

I have a dataframe df1 with latitude and longitude.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
     'place': ["London", "Paris", "Berlin", "London", "Berlin"],
     'sale': [12, 6, 4, 3, 14],
     'lat': [54, 23, 13, 54, 13],
     'lon': [13, 32, 64, 13, 64],
     })
df1

    place  sale lat lon
0   London  12  54  13
1   Paris   6   23  32
2   Berlin  4   13  64
3   London  3   54  13
4   Berlin  14  13  64
```

After aggregating `sale` I get a second dataframe:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({
     'place': ["London", "Paris", "Berlin"],
     'sale_sum': [15, 6, 18],
     })
df2

   place  sale_sum
0   London  15
1   Paris   6
2   Berlin  18
```

Now I want to append the lat and lon to the second dataframe. Result would be like this:

```
    place  sale_sum lat lon
0   London    15    54  13
1   Paris     6     23  32
2   Berlin   18     13  64
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
a = df2.merge(df1[['place','lat', 'lon']], on='place')
a.loc[~a.duplicated()]
>place  sale_sum    lat lon
0   London  15  54  13
2   Paris   6   23  32
3   Berlin  18  13  64
```

Answer (score 0):

Use pandas `merge()`:

```
pd.merge(df1, df2, how='inner', on='place')
```

Comment: If you output this, there are duplicate rows because of the original `sale` column. This modified version of your answer give what I think OP askes for `pd.merge(df1.drop('sale', axis=1), df2, how='inner', on='place').drop_duplicates()`